# GLFW crashes when pressing down all 4 DPAD buttons

Tags: c++, input, glfw, gamepad

I am trying to add game controller support into my application and it works for every button so far. However, my controller allows me to press down the whole DPAD button (all 4 directions) and it triggers an ASSERT within GLFW. It shouldn't cause me too much issues however I would like to know if it is an issue caused on my part and is there a way to prevent this on my side?

[image]

[image]

GLFW Code that failed:

```
// Notifies shared code of the new value of a joystick hat
//
void _glfwInputJoystickHat(_GLFWjoystick* js, int hat, char value)
{
    int base;

    assert(js != NULL);
    assert(hat >= 0);
    assert(hat < js->hatCount);

    // Valid hat values only use the least significant nibble and have at most two bits
    // set, which can be considered adjacent plus an arbitrary rotation within the nibble
    assert((value & 0xf0) == 0);
    assert((value & ((value << 2) | (value >> 2))) == 0);

    base = js->buttonCount + hat * 4;

    js->buttons[base + 0] = (value & 0x01) ? GLFW_PRESS : GLFW_RELEASE;
    js->buttons[base + 1] = (value & 0x02) ? GLFW_PRESS : GLFW_RELEASE;
    js->buttons[base + 2] = (value & 0x04) ? GLFW_PRESS : GLFW_RELEASE;
    js->buttons[base + 3] = (value & 0x08) ? GLFW_PRESS : GLFW_RELEASE;

    js->hats[hat] = value;
}
```

Comment: valid question, please paste your code instead of posting this screenshot for future references.

Comment: After you pressed Retry what did `value` contain?

Comment: @drescherjm value=15